# proc sql correlation

Tags: sql, sas, correlation

Can anybody help me that how I can calculate the correlation between two variables within each group in Proc Sql? Is there any such function just as sum or mean? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Why do you want to do this in SQL? You have SAS, so use the appropriate tool - in this case, `proc corr`.

Comment: I want to do something like proc sql; select groupvar, corr(var1, var2) from table group by groupvar; I need the correlation variable to be one column in the final aggregated dataset.

Comment: please post some sample data and show expected result

Comment: Hi, Basically it's a collapse (aggregation) of the datasets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `proc corr` to start with, as this does all the required calculations, which gets you most of the way there. You will need to filter and transpose the output dataset into your desired format. There are many answers on this site showing how to do that sort of thing, so have a look at those - in this case a wide to long transposition is required.

```
proc sort data = sashelp.class out = class;
  by sex;
run;

proc corr data = class outp=mypcorr noprint;
  var HEIGHT WEIGHT;
  by SEX;
run;
```